# СКАЗКА ЛОЖЬ ДА В НЕЙ НАМЕК ДОБРЫМ МОЛОДЦАМ УРОК

Tags: синтаксис, недопустимая-метка

СКОЛЬКО ЧАСТЕЙ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ? КАКИМ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ: ПРОСТЫМ ИЛИ СЛОЖНЫМ?

Comment: @МАНЯ, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сказка ложь (1), да (2)в ней намек), (3) добрым молодцам урок.

Сложное предложение состоит из трех простых предложений.

Сочинительная связь (союз ДА) между (1) и (2), (3).

Бессоюзная связь между (2) и (3).

Предложения (2) и (3) - эллиптические, построенные по схеме "дополнение - подлежащее".

В предложение (1) нет тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, так как отсутствует пауза в устойчивом сочетании.

Answer (score 2):

СКАЗКА ЛОЖЬ - это первое предложение. ДА В НЕЙ НАМЕК, ДОБРЫМ МОЛОДЦАМ УРОК - второе предложение. Следовательно, это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из 2-х простых, соединенных союзом "да".